# How to rotate the camera around itself using python?

Tags: python, camera, transforms

Since I am not sure how to describe the behaviour I want, I paste it below.
[image]

[image]

I tried to use rotation_euler property, but it doesnt work as I wanted.
I tried also to look at the command in the info panel when I rotate it manually. It uses bpy.ops.transform.rotate(), however it requires an orient_matrix that I don't know how to define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a manner to do what I intended. It may be the not most simple or efficient but it does the job so I am leaving it here in case anyone needs.

```
def spin_camera():
 cam = bpy.data.objects['Camera1']
 location = cam.location.copy() #copy current location
 right, up, back = cam.matrix_world.to_3x3().transposed()
 direction = np.cross(up,right) #gets direction that the camera is looking to
 angle = 45 
 rotation_vertical = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(angle), 3, mathutils.Vector( direction ))
 matrix = rotation_vertical @ cam.matrix_world.to_3x3() 
 cam.matrix_world = matrix.to_4x4()
 cam.location = location #after assigning the matrix, the camera is moved to the origin, so it is necessary to move it to the previous location again.
```